# Function only works when flipped

Tags: idris

Why does it error?

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.Vect.Quantifiers

get : (i : Fin n) -> All (flip Vect t) ls -> Vect (index i ls) t
get FZ (y :: z) = y
get (FS y) (z :: w) = get y w

nproject : Vect l (n : _  ** Fin (index n ls)) -> All (flip Vect t) ls -> Vect l t
nproject [] _ = []
nproject ((n ** i)::fs) vs = index i (get n vs) :: nproject fs vs
```

This only runs if I flip `nproject`:

```
*VectExtensions> flip nproject [[0]] [(0 ** 0)]
[0] : Vect 1 Integer
*VectExtensions> nproject [(0 ** 0)] [[0]]
When checking argument pf to constructor Builtins.MkDPair:
        Type mismatch between
                IsJust (Just x)
        and
                IsJust (integerToFin 0 n)
```

But it works with an explicit `ls`:

```
*VectExtensions> nproject {ls=[_]} [(0 ** 0)] [[0]]
[0] : Vect 1 Integer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors comes from `integerToFin : Integer -> (n : Nat) -> Maybe (Fin n)`. It is used by the REPL because you use `(0 ** 0)` instead of `(FZ ** FZ)`. The REPL knows that this is just syntax and you really want a `Fin n` and not an `Integer`. So the REPL first tries to convert and `(0 ** 0)` becomes internally `(integerToFin 0 n ** integerToFin 0 m)`. Because of the type inference implementation it thinks about the case of `n=Z`. And so `integerToFin 0 Z = Nothing` instead of `Just Fin n`.

To solve this you could help a bit:

```
> nproject [(FZ ** 0)] [[0]] 
[0] : Vect 1 Integer
```

Or

```
> nproject [(0 ** FZ)] [[0]] 
[0] : Vect 1 Integer
```

---

So, why does this error?

This depends on the implementation of the type inference of the compiler and if I see this correct, it is just not smart enough for this case. :-)

I guess the problem is roughly the following:

This is `:t nproject`:

```
nproject : Vect l (n : Fin n ** Fin (index n ls)) -> All (flip Vect t) ls -> Vect l t
```

`n` could be `0` and thus `integerToFin 0 0 = Nothing`.

In the flipped case, `n` is known to be `1`, because it tries to infer the implicit arguments and `[[0]]` before `(0 ** 0)`. Then the REPL can infer that `integerToFin 0 (S Z) = Just FZ`